# I want to see (if any) a version of this theorem for the case of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, prime-numbers, finite-fields

**Theorem**: For polynomials modulo $m$, for a number $m≥2$, we have: if $r$ is a root of the polynomial $f$, then division of $f$ by $x-r$ yields remainder $0$.
This means: It is possible to write $$f(x) = (x-r)q(x)$$ for some (quotient)
polynomial $q$.

This result is for a single variable $x$. I wante to see (if any) a version of this threorem for the case of a multivariate polynomial $f$ with

1) two variables $x,y$.

2) three variables $x,y,z$.

Comment: Is there a reason for the finite fields tags? They are not mentioned in the problem statement. I am asking because $k[x,y]$ is never a principle ideal domain and perhaps [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz) for algebraically closed (so certainly infinite) fields is about as close as you can get in the multivariate case (and "close" is very relative here)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It is for polynomials modulo $m$.